# Not displaying items which match criteria in Oracle SQL Developer but no error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the code below and I used this to display fields from the wh_id of 'MP'

```
select o.wh_id, o.bill_to_code, d.create_date,
   (case when d.pick_area like 'GPS%' then 'GPS' else d.pick_area
    end) as pick_area,
    count(*) as OUC
from t_order o INNER JOIN
 t_pick_detail d
 on o.order_number = d.order_number
where o.wh_id = 'MP'
group by o.wh_id, o.bill_to_code, d.create_date,
     (case when d.pick_area like 'GPS%' then 'GPS' else d.pick_area
    end)
order by o.bill_to_code
```

It gave me the following results:

[image]

Then once I add in one piece of extra criteria which matches items in the table above.

extra criteria is:

```
AND d.create_date =  '19-FEB-15'
```

Full code is now :

```
select o.wh_id, o.bill_to_code, d.create_date,
   (case when d.pick_area like 'GPS%' then 'GPS' else d.pick_area
    end) as pick_area,
    count(*) as OUC
from t_order o INNER JOIN
 t_pick_detail d
 on o.order_number = d.order_number
where o.wh_id = 'MP' AND d.create_date =  '19-FEB-15'
group by o.wh_id, o.bill_to_code, d.create_date,
     (case when d.pick_area like 'GPS%' then 'GPS' else d.pick_area
    end)
order by o.bill_to_code
```

Now all the results that I get are shown below, but it makes it seem as though there are no results with that info which there are as you can see from above print screen. I don't get any error though.

[image]

Hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: `d.create_date = TO_DATE('19-Feb-15','DD-Mon-YY')` should help.

Comment: I just tried didn't seem to make a difference though :( thank you for trying

Comment: Definitely create_date column is storing timestamp also. You once should try `trunc(d.create_date) = TO_DATE('19-FEB-15','DD-MON-YY')`.

Comment: I cant seem to add that in it wants 3 choices in the brackets like (d,create_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY', Something else), it is a date column.

Comment: Don't use TRUNC, use a date range. Trunc will suppress any index on the column.

Answer (score 1):

From a performance point of view, I would not suggest to use **TRUNC** as it would **not** use any **regular index** on the DATE column.

Better use a **RANGE** condition. It will use the index on the date column and you would see an **index range scan** rather than a **FULL TABLE scan**.

For example,

```
d.create_date >= to_date('19-FEB-15', 'DD-MON-YY')
AND
d.create_date < to_date('19-FEB-15 ', 'DD-MON-YY') + 1
```

Or,

```
d.create_date 
BETWEEN to_date('19-FEB-15', 'DD-MON-YY') 
AND     to_date('19-FEB-15 ', 'DD-MON-YY') + 1
```

If you really want to use `TRUNC`, then you would have to create a **function_based index**.

Have a look at this link https://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/impact-of-the-trunc-function-on-an-indexed-date-column/

Answer (score 0):

Definitely create_date column is storing timestamp also. You once should try trunc(d.create_date) = TO_DATE('19-FEB-15','DD-MON-YY').

This worked Sam thank you :)